# is TLS used throughout wss connection or just when connect?

Tags: go, websocket

I plan to write an secure websocket server in golang. My question is:

Is TLS used throughout the entire connection when using `wss://`, or is it just used when upgrade from http(s) to websocket protocol?

The reason I ask is that as I understand the websocket protocol has nothing to do with http except that the connection is initiated via http(s).

So, if I use `ListenAndServeTLS` in my Go program, can I ensure that the entire websocket conversation is secure?

Comment: If the client connected using TLS, then the connection will use TLS. I don't think I understand the question, because if you're only listening with TLS, there's no other way the client could connect.

Comment: If you use ListenAndServeTLS, then all websocket traffic will use TLS.